# Override Wordpress core function _wp_mysql_week()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function, overriding

I would like to override the `_wp_mysql_week()` wordpress function located in `wp-includes/functions.php` since the actual `_wp_mysql_week()` is not complying with the ISO 8601 and asking the mode 1 to the `WEEK()` MYSQL function instead of the mode 3.

I'd like to put a filter or something in the theme functions.php but couldn't find how.

Thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this function is rigged up in WP 4.1, if you specify "Monday" as the first day of the week in the options table, you'll get ISO8601:1988 week numbers (MySQL Mode 1). Otherwise you'll get mode 0.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

You can also intervene with a filter after the query is constructed but before it's passed over to MySQL. In your filter you can muck around with the text of the query to change

```
WEEK( something, 0 )
```

to

```
WEEK( something, 1 )
```

to get your ISO 8601:1988 behavior. This explains query filtering.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses

Notice that the _wp_mysql_week function helpfully generates its output with spaces where I have shown pound signs here.

```
WEEK(#something,#1#)
```

If your week starts on some day besides Sunday or Monday, the generated query code looks like this:

```
WEEK(#DATE_SUB(#something,#INTERVAL#3#DAY#),#0#)
```

So, you can probably use a regex in your filter to search for

```
WEEK( .+? 0 )
```

then change the digit to 1. But of course regexs have hazards.

You could also request that a new filter be added specifically to the output of _wp_mysql_week in order to allow user code to control it. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/  The WordPress team is generally receptive to such requests.